# Вызов трех хранимых процедур jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, jdbc

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему это

```
public class Main {

private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "root";


public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Driver driver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        Connection connection = getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Не удалось загрузить класс драйвера!");
    }

    public static void sel (Connection connection) {
    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("{CALL sel}");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1) + " " + resultSet.getString(2));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void ins_upd (Connection connection, int ID, String NAME) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement pstmp = connection.prepareStatement("{CALL ins_upd(?,?)}");
            pstmp.setInt(1, ID);
            pstmp.setString(2, NAME);
            System.out.println("Готово!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void del (Connection connection, int ID) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement pstmp = connection.prepareStatement("{CALL del(?)}");
            pstmp.setInt(1, ID);
            System.out.println("Готово!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
 }
```

выдает ошибки:

```
Error26, 9) java: illegal start of expression
Error26, 16) java: illegal start of expression
Error26, 22) java: ';' expected
Error26, 28) java: not a statement
Error26, 31) java: ';' expected
```

Задумывалось как методы для трех хранимых процедур для веб-сервера, но я их получается не так оформил?

Comment: Кто это выдает вам такие ошибки - чем вы компилируете? Если вы воспользуетесь какой-нибудь приличной IDE, она сразу вам покажет, что у вас не соблюдается синтаксис Java. Где кончается тело метода `public static void main(String[] args)` ? Объявление метода `public static void sel (Connection connection)` - это часть класса или часть метода `main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я обычно при вызове хранимых процедур работаю с CallableStatement

Приведу фрагмент кода может Вам поможет.

```
private static final String QUERY = "{? = call TEST(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

try(CallableStatement cstmt =  conn.prepareCall (QUERY)){
    cstmt.registerOutParameter (1, Types.INTEGER);
    cstmt.setString(2, clientID);
    cstmt.setString(3, reqId);
    cstmt.setString(4, login);
    cstmt.setString(5, key);
    ......
    cstmt.execute();
    int ans = cstmt.getInt(1);

}
```

UPDATE !!!

```
 public static void sel (Connection connection) {
        try(CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{CALL sel}")){ 
                boolean hadResults = statement.execute();

                while (hadResults) {
                    try(ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet()){

                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1) + " " + resultSet.getString(2));

                    }
                    }catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }

                    hadResults = statement.getMoreResults();
                }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }

 public static void ins_upd (Connection connection, int ID, String NAME) {

    try(CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{CALL ins_upd(?,?)}")){
        statement.setInt(1, ID);
        statement.setString(2, NAME);
        boolean hadResults = statement.execute();

        ///// if stored procedure has result
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }

 public static void del (Connection connection, int ID) { 
    try(CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{CALL del(?)}")){
        statement.setInt(1, ID);
        boolean hadResults = statement.execute();

        ///// if stored procedure has result

    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
```

Comment: А если у меня три хранимые процедуры? Для каждой отдельный метод сделать? Извините, я ещё плохо знаю язык, может есть пример полного кода хотя бы с двумя процедурами?

Comment: Это зависит от логики Вашего предложение, но обычно надо разделит на методы

Comment: Обновил ответ под Ваш код, если будут вопросы обращайтесь

Comment: Спасибо большое, переделал на ваш вариант. Следующим пунктом у меня был интерфейс. Хочу сделать html страницу, в которой можно вызывать нужную процедуру, не подскажете что переделать? Я собирался в html добавить вызов процедуры по названию метода, типо <form action="main.java" method="sel">, но это не сработает. Если вас не затруднит, не могли бы написать на почту drhev@yandex.ru

Comment: Веб уже решается с помощью Java EE.

Comment: Можете Spring Boot посмотреть он более легкий фре́ймворк для Java EE

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Привет!

Проходим в этом семестре JSF аппликации. Нам показывали такой метод подключения к ДБ. 
Необходим драйвер `mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar` для подключения. 
Через контроллеры передаём запросы юзер со странички в ДАО, там запрос обрабатывается и возвращается назад в контроллер в виде объекта содержащий то, что запрашевалось.

Может подойдёт?

**Простой вариант:**

```
package ie.gmit.sw;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException;
import com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException;
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;



public class Public_Holiday {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name;

        try {

            MysqlDataSource mysqlDS = new MysqlDataSource();

            mysqlDS.setURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/superheroes");
            mysqlDS.setUser("root");
            mysqlDS.setPassword("");

            Connection connect = mysqlDS.getConnection();
            Statement myStmt = connect.createStatement();

            System.out.println("Enter superhero name: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            name = sc.nextLine();
            sc.close();

            String query = "delete from superhero_table where name like '" + name + "'";

            int rs = myStmt.executeUpdate(query);
            //System.out.println(rs);
            if(rs == 0){
                System.out.println("Superhero with name '" + name + "' does not exist in DB!" );
            }




        } catch (CommunicationsException communication_failure){
            System.out.println(communication_failure.getMessage() + "\nCan not reach the server!");
        } catch(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException dependancy_deletion){
             System.out.println(dependancy_deletion.getMessage() + "\nDelete superhero from any dependant tables first.");
        } catch( SQLException se){
            //System.out.println(se.getMessage());
            se.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

**Вариант с подключением к JSF.** В этом случае мы храним драйвер mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar в деректории lib на стороне клиента. 
Если есть желание, можешь заглянуть на мой репозиторий https://github.com/EddyCodeIt/JSF-MySql-Application, посмотреть идеи.

```
package ie.gmit.sw;

import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class DAO {

    // mysqlDS object 
    private DataSource mysqlDS;

    // DAO() constructor
    public DAO() throws Exception {
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        String jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/garage"; 
        mysqlDS = (DataSource) context.lookup(jndiName);
    }

    /* Query Database for _____ details */
    public ArrayList<Garage> getManufacturerDetails() throws SQLException{

        // create new array list  to store data from obtained from DB. Later we return this ArrayList
        ArrayList<Garage> manufacturers = new ArrayList<>();

        // connect to database and prepare statement 
        Connection conn = mysqlDS.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement myStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from manufacturer");
        ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            String manu_code = rs.getString("manu_code");
            String manu_name = rs.getString("manu_name");
            String manu_details = rs.getString("manu_details");

            manufacturers.add(new Garage(manu_code, manu_name, manu_details));
        }

        conn.close();
        myStmt.close();
        return manufacturers;
    }
```

Извини если не в тему ответил :)

Comment: А если знаете, что отвечаете не в тему, то зачем тогда отвечаете вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в приведенном тексте не соблюден синтаксис Java. Объявление метода не может быть частью тела другого метода. У вас же тело (программный код) метода `main` плавно переходит в объявление метода `sel`, как будто объявление метода является частью кода.

Comment: Получается надо просто вытянуть методы sel,  ins_upd, del из метода main?

Comment: Ну для начала. Вообще я бы посоветовал ознакомиться хотя бы с основами языка прежде, чем писать работу с БД или еще что-то такое. Если у вас программа элементарно не компилируется, и не по невнимательности (что с каждым иногда случается), а по незнанию самых элементарных основ языка, то говорить о какой-то полезной функциональности такой программы - сильно преждевременно.